# How to Iterate objects inside objects using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a collection of objects that looks like this:

```
[{
  "mainObj": "main1",
  "subObjArray":{
                 "subObj": "sub1",
                 "deepSubObjArray":[{
                                     "deepSubObj": "deep1",
                                     "property": "something",
                                     },{
                                     "deepSubObj": "deep2",
                                     "property": "somethingElse"
                                   }]
               },
  },{
  "mainObj": "main2",
  "subObjArray":{
                 "subObj": "sub2",
                 "deepSubObjArray":[{
                                     "deepSubObj": "deep3",
                                     "property": "something",
                                     },{
                                     "deepSubObj": "deep4",
                                     "property": "somethingElse"
                                   }]
               },
}]
```

If I use:

```
<tr ng-repeat="mainObj in mainObjArray">
<td>{{mainObj}}</td>
<td>{{mainObj.subObjArray.deepSubObjArray}}</td>
```

I get the whole object string and the array of "deepSubObj" string as expected, but if i try:

```
<tr ng-repeat="mainObj in mainObjArray">
<div ng-repeat="deepSubObj in mainObj.subObjArray.deepSubObjArray">
<td>{{deepSubObj}}</td>
</div></tr>
```

I get nothing.

Is this not the correct way to iterate through that array? What else could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `ng-repeat` tags are nested, [everything is straightforward](http://plnkr.co/edit/aOBIg85om7WTqSe4ifaM?p=preview).

The problem is related to layout and not to `ng-repeat` iteration. `<div>` tag is not allowed in tables outside of `<td>` tag, this will cause the table to be rendered incorrectly.

Using nested `ngRepeat` directives may be harmful for performance, depending on the objects. Preparing the data before its output is often a better solution.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I meant: 
ng-repeat="mainObj in mainObjArray"
ng-repeat="deepSubObj in mainObj.subObjArray.deepSubObjArray"

Edited, but I think you read it before that.

Comment: @ArtemioRamirez It isn't valid html. If you do this on the same element, then no, it won't work. Nested ng-repeat should be nested elements, <div ng-repeat=...><div ng-repeat=...></div></div>

Comment: I'm actually using <tr ng-repeat><div ng-repeat></div></tr>

Comment: @ArtemioRamirez I've updated the answer according to current code.

Comment: That was exactly my problem, solved by using <tr ng-repeat><td><div ng-repeat></div></td></tr> Thx a lot.

Answer (score 2):

## html

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="mainObj in mainObjArray">
            {{mainObj.mainObj}}
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="deepSubObj in mainObj.subObjArray.deepSubObjArray">
                    {{deepSubObj.deepSubObj}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

## js

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
        .controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.mainObjArray = [{
                "mainObj": "main1",
                "subObjArray": {
                    "subObj": "sub1",
                    "deepSubObjArray": [{
                        "deepSubObj": "deep1",
                        "property": "something",
                    }, {
                        "deepSubObj": "deep2",
                        "property": "somethingElse"
                    }]
                },
            }, {
                "mainObj": "main2",
                "subObjArray": {
                    "subObj": "sub2",
                    "deepSubObjArray": [{
                        "deepSubObj": "deep3",
                        "property": "something",
                    }, {
                        "deepSubObj": "deep4",
                        "property": "somethingElse"
                    }]
                },
            }]
        });
```

## effect

[image]